# Forums 'Add Container' function not doing anything

Tags: 7, nodes

I have enabled the Forum module and ran into some rather annoying errors:

1. No 'Forum' link comes up in admin, I have to go directly to *admin/content/forum*
2. I click on 'Add Container' or 'Add Forum' and nothing happens
3. When I click on 'Create Content' I cannot see type forum (only when I view content types)
4. When I direct to node/add/forum I cannot create as the Forum dropdown box is empty (as I can't create Containers

I have run cron and update to no prevail. I read something somewhere it helps to manually update the database by incrementing the container row count or something?

Comment: No idea, but try to re-install Forum (first disable, and then click on the Uninstall tab and uninstall it there, then enable it again) and try again.

Comment: I will try when I get home and keep this question updated, cheers.

Comment: Is this a clean installation?

Comment: No, it has had a bit of work done to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I flushed the cache and it worked.
I created a flush.php file and ran it.

```
<?php
  drupal_flush_all_caches();
  drupal_set_message('cache flushed.');
?>
```

More information is available [here](http://drupal.org/node/152983).